# Update TD value in jQuery given a data-id attribute

Tags: jquery

I got in trouble trying to update a value into a TD cell given a data-id attribute of next td cell.
Is it possible in jQuery?
What I'm aiming to do is: into a table each row has some actions into the last cell, this last cell has a data-id attribute; among those action there is the possibility to add an image using a modal upload form; after submitted the image I want to update the image counter for that TR row incrementing the TD related cell.
Thanks a lot for any help

Here you are the code to append new rows into a table.

```
$.ajax({
            url: url + "/photos/ajax_search",   
            data: post_data,
            type: "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#ajax-container').hide();
            },
            success: function (data) {

                if(data.status)
                {

                    var len = data.rows.length;
                    for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                        var id = data.rows[i].id;
                        var manufacturer = data.rows[i].manufacturer;
                        var model = data.rows[i].model;
                        var cn = data.rows[i].cn;
                        var built = data.rows[i].built;
                        var count = data.rows[i].count;
                        var action = data.rows[i].action;

                        var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + manufacturer + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + model + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + cn + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + built + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + count + "</td>" +
                            "<td data-id='" + id + "'>" + action + "</td>" +
                            "</tr>";

                        $("#table tbody").append(tr_str); 
                    }
                    $('#ajax-container').show();
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log('Registration not in DB');
                }
            },
            complete:function(data){

                $(this).parent().removeClass("spinner");
            }
        })
```

The action cell include some icons, to show a modal form and upload image or file for each aircraft in row.
After submitting the form to upload the image, if successful, i need to update the count value in the TD cell appended above.
Here you are the code that submit the form to upload the file ( it works fine so far )

```
$('#upload-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $("#register-id").val();
    console.log("Submitted id is " + id);

    // Create an FormData object 
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    var form_action  = $("#modal-form").find("form").attr("action");
    // Add token hash in FormData
    formData.append("csrf_test_name", token_hash); 

    $.ajax({
        url: form_action,
        type:"post",

        data: formData,
        processData:false,
        contentType:false,
        dataType: "json",

        beforeSend: function(){
            $('.uploadBtn').prop("disabled", true);
            $('#upload-form').css("opacity",".5");

        },
        success: function(data){

            $('.uploadBtn').prop("disabled", false);
            $('#upload-form').css("opacity","1");

        }

    })
```

I tried the following code but it returns the text of entire row selected...I need just the count value in the 4th cell

```
$('#table').find("td[data-id='" + id + "']").parent().text();
```

Comment: Please add your working code or create a fiddle or codepen, so it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jan, I have actual code. The script is complex and made of several parts, I think the most important one related to the issue is the first part, where the rows are appended to the table.

Comment: I tried the following code to get the count value in TD cell....but it return the text into the last td cell. var count = $('#table').find("td[data-id='" + id + "']").text();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not quite sure I understand you. You say you make ID's for TR's based on the Record Id from the JSON file, but then you say that you want to increment it? I presume that you want to add new rows from the JSON set or is it something else?

Regarding your script: What you are doing here is to find the matching cell and then with parent() you move up to the row and thus you get the whole row as text:

```
$('#table').find("td[data-id='" + id + "']").parent().text();
```

I would suggest that you put an id on that 4th cell like "data-count-id" + id, so you'd be able to address it directly like:

```
$('#table').find("td[data-count-id='" + id + "']").text();
```

If that's not an option, you could do it a bit convoluted like this:

```
= $((($('#table').find("td[data-id='" + id + 
"']").parent().children()).toArray())[4]).text();
```

Which is that you request the parent row (TR), get all the children (TD), turned into an array and request the 4t cell as text. If you intend it to use as a number you probably need to do a parseInt too.

--- edit ---

Just keeping to the syntax that you begin with, but instead of adding a custom attribute, it could also have been using the usual identifier "id" and named it like

```
<td id='data-count-" + id + "'>
```

to be able to call it as:

```
$("#data-count-" + id).text();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for feedback and sorry for the poor english. I fixed following your first suggestion...adding an id data attribute to the 4th cell to update the image count value directly as soon as uploaded the new file.

Comment: It was a bit of a challenge, but it wasn't so bad ;) See "edit" for an additional alternative.